# Enabling rp_filter loose (#2) mode for IPv6

Tags: iptables, ipv6, sysctl

does anyone have a solution to make **reverse path filtering** work (in loose mode) also for **IPv6** and not only for IPv4?

The setup I am having is a machine1 connected directly to a machine2, while machine1 being also connected to outside net.

**The targetted traffic is this:**
Client (from the outside net) sends a request to the machine1 which then forwards the request to the machine2.

**Obvious problem:** When packet gets handled by machine1, it forwards it to a port connected to machine2, but with source IP of a client. This would normally be seen as a spoofed ip - but that's what rp_filter is for, right?

Normally on machine1 I would do (for IPv4):

`echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/<interface_to_outside_net>/rp_filter`

and everything would work, but for IPv6 this is not the case since rp_filter is not implemented in the kernel for IPv6 as of yet.
The only solution I know of would be to set up ip6tables.

Current settings: 

`ip6tables -t raw -N RPFILTER
ip6tables -t raw -A RPFILTER -m rpfilter -j RETURN
ip6tables -t raw -A RPFILTER -m rpfilter --loose -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j RPFILTER`

But for some reason traffic never reaches machine2 and on the client side I get timeout.

Using tcpdump on machine1 I get only the SYN of TCP handshake.:

`14:18:50.390292 IP6 fd11:3456:789a:1::4.34184 > fd12:3456:789a:1::1.1111: Flags [S], seq 701159610, win 28800, options [mss 1440,sackOK,TS val 6066549 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0`

nothing else...

Any advice?

Comment: What Linux distribution did you use? What kernel version? What firewall?

Comment: OS Ubuntu 18.04 (xenial), kernel 4.4.0-139-generic, firewall not configured at all. Those commands above are the first I used. Default policy is set to ACCEPT if I check iptables.

Comment: I also tried running only with `ip6tables -t raw -A PREROUTING -m rpfilter --loose -j ACCEPT` .. but did not help

Comment: Are you sure that machine1 is actually routing traffic?

Comment: Well it should be (again its doing the routing for IPv4), but something's gotta be wrong for IPv6. I am tracing the packets in iptables now.

Comment: Insisting again with MichaelHampton 's question: can you give the setting proving machine1 is configured to route packets for IPv6 (which is distinct from IPv4)? Anyway you can forget about ip6tables for now: no rule will make it accept more than it already accepts without any restriction.

Comment: Routes looked ok from the beginning and ping worked.

machine1: ```ip route
fd11:3456:789a:1::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 256  pref medium
fd12:3456:789a:1::1 via fd11:3456:789a:1::2 dev eth1 proto bird metric 64  pref medium
```
machine2: ```ip route
fd11:3456:789a:1::/64 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fd12:3456:789a:1::1 dev ip6tnl0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
```

Just posting the answer... Actually found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

***SPOILER***

The problem was actually related to the fact that I did not set up the IPv6 addresses using `/etc/network/interfaces/` but "only" using `ip a a ...`.
I never thought that this could somehow be a different, but it turned out to be the case this time.

**STEPS leading to SOLUTION:**

During the investigation I did a simple ping6 from machine2 towards machine1 which strangely fixed the problem I was having.

After this, the TCP handshake got correctly created and I was able to do a `curl -g -6 ..` which was the target command I wanted to do and I was like YES finally!

But then I was like ...this doesn't make sense, why is ICMPv6 not taking care of this? 
This made me thinking that I should check ndp (`ip -6 neigh show`) table which actually showed me that entry for machine1 had **FAILED**.

Which means that for some reason ICMPv6 was failing to exchange neighbor solicitations/advertisements.

At the end I remembered that simple pc reboot usually fixes all the problems, but since I configured my interfaces using only `ip a a ...` this would flush my configuration, so what I did was configured `/etc/network/interfaces/` with proper IPv6 addresses and rebooted machines.

This was the source of all the problems ;)

**SOLUTION**:

Don't do anything in regards of rp_filter in loose mode for IPv6 ==> it's enabled by default.

Just make sure, that you have properly configured your interfaces :)

*PS: Does anyone know what I messed up? Why wasn't I able to simply use `ip address add....`? Thanks.*

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem, thanks for noticing me to check `ip -6 neigh show`.

In my case it's that endpoint does not belong to the same network id(prefix).

Example:

Machine A fd00:1:1/64%eth0 will only answer its MAC address to neighbor solicitation message of fd00:1:1 coming from eth0.

If Machine A also has a fd00:2::1/64%eth1, it won't answer fd00:2::1 request if it's coming from eth0, supposedly.